# Juntar linhas de um arquivo texto

Tags: algoritmo

Dado um arquivo texto com o layout abaixo:

```
VASCO;JOGADOR_1
VASCO;JOGADOR_2
VASCO;JOGADOR_3
PALMEIRAS;JOGADOR_4
PALMEIRAS;JOGADOR_5
PALMEIRAS;JOGADOR_6
PALMEIRAS;JOGADOR_7
```

Como criar uma lógica  (preferência por bash, python ou java) para obter o resultado abaixo:

```
VASCO;JOGADOR_1,JOGADOR_2,JOGADOR_3
PALMEIRAS;JOGADOR_4,JOGADOR_5,JOGADOR_6,JOGADOR7
```

Não sei quantos times e quantos jogadores por time terá no arquivo texto.

Resumir em cada linha do arquivo gerado uma linha contendo o nome do time ponto-vírgula a lista de jogadores do respectivo time separado por vírgula (o último jogador não deve ter vírgula ao final)

Até o momento consegui criar em java parte do código, para ler o arquivo e começar a separar o que é time e o que é jogador.
Estou pesquisando sobre listas para tentar fazer uma lista de times e cada lista de times ter uma lista de jogadores, e ir adicionando os elementos em tempo de execução, é uma boa alternativa?

```
public class Principal {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String time;
    String jogador;

    String nomeArquivo = "input.txt";
    FileReader arquivoEntrada = new FileReader(nomeArquivo);
    BufferedReader bufferArquivoEntrada = new BufferedReader(arquivoEntrada);
    String linha = bufferArquivoEntrada.readLine();
    while(linha != null){
        System.out.println(linha);
        String[] linhaSplit = linha.split(";");
        time = linhaSplit[0];
        jogador = linhaSplit[1];
        System.out.println("Time........: " + time);
        System.out.println("Funcionario.: " + jogador);
        linha = bufferArquivoEntrada.readLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tentou alguma coisa? Qual dificuldade encontrada? A mim parece um trabalho de faculdade que você nem sabe por onde começar rs

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção e entendo seus questionamentos. É um projeto pessoal, não de faculdade mas você está certo. Já fiz algumas coisas em bash mas minha dificuldade maior nesse momento e estruturar a lógica mesmo para esse caso específico

Comment: Posso responder uma logica possivel de se usar, mas veja que ficaria ampla demais.... existem algumas formas de se obter o mesmo resultado, e não limitando ainda qual a linguagem pretende usar, fica mais amplo ainda rs

Comment: Recomendo diminuir pelo menos o escopo da pergunta "Pretendo usar essa linguagem" já melhoraria um pouco

Comment: Se puder também postar o que tentou e qual foi a dificuldade encontrada (estruturação da logica), direcionaria melhor a quem se interessar em responder a pergunta

Comment: Marcelo, obrigado. Nesse momento estou no ônibus rs, logo que possível adiciono algo que já tentei. Minha preferência é por java, bash (linux) ou python por já ter brincado um pouco com estas linguagens

Comment: Estou pensando em iniciar a lógica da seguinte forma: Ler o arquivo linha a linha, para cada linha separar o conteúdo em duas variáveis  (splitando por porto vírgula) queria que o conteúdo da esquera fosse o nome de um array ou lista, e seu valor adiciono à um array de controle. O conteúdo da direita adicionado ao array que tem o nome na esquerda) para linha seguinte verifica se o conteúdo da esquersa existe no array de controle, se já existir apenas adicionar o novo elemento, caso contrário criar novo array... no final itero sobre cada array adicionando a vírgula para separar elementos

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/205196/edit) sua pergunta e poste nela mesmo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um algoritmo como esse:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final File file = new File("input.txt");
        final FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        final String content = new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        final Map<String, Set<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (final String line : content.split("\n")) {
            final String[] array = line.split(";");
            final String team = array[0];
            final String player = array[1];

            if (map.containsKey(team)) {
                map.get(team).add(player);
            } else {
                final Set<String> players = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                players.add(player);
                map.put(team, players);
            }
        }

        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(map.size());

        for (final Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(entry.getKey() + ";");
            final Iterator<String> iterator = entry.getValue().iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                builder.append(iterator.next()).append(iterator.hasNext() ? "," : "");
            }

            lines.add(builder.toString());
        }

        final Path outputFile = Paths.get("output.txt");
        Files.write(outputFile, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Input: \n" + content);
        System.out.println("Output: \n" + lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pedro, muito obrigado! Fiz um teste usando seu código com uma pequena massa de dados e o resultado parece ser 100% o esperado. Irei estudar bastante os conceitos que você utilizou para aprender mais. Algo na minha cabeça falava "usar algo com chave-valor" mas o desenvolvimento saía. O pulo do gato aí foi o uso do LinkedHashMap certo? Irei estudar sobre ele. Estou marcando sua resposta como a correta! Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Comment: Sim, tanto o LinkedHashMap como o LinkedHashSet, pois ambas mantém ordem de inserção.

Answer (score 1):

Podemos supor que usamos `bash 4` para cima, certo? Nesse caso, temos vetores associativos/mapeamentos. Como estamos trabalhando com texto, esse é o tipo de variável básica do `bash`, então estamos em casa.

Vamos chamar nosso shell de `cria_times.sh`, beleza? Como todo bom shell script, vamos deixar ele o mais flexível possível assumindo a entrada padrão. Para receber do arquivo `input.txt`, basta executar o seguinte comando: `./cria_times.sh < input.txt`.

A ideia básica aqui é loopar sobre esses conceitos:

1. a linha tem o formato `<TIME>` `;` `<JOGADOR>`
2. leio a linha e separo os componentes `<TIME>` e `<JOGADOR>`
3. adiciono `<JOGADOR>` ao vetor posicional identificado por `<TIME>`

Para fazer um loop de leitura simples, eu gosto de sempre começar assim:

```
initialize

while read LINHA; do
    do_something
done
```

Pois bem, agora precisamos por aqueles 3 passos apontados acima dentro do `do_something` e inicializar as coisas no `initialize`. Como dito logo no começo, eu preciso fazer uma associação entre time e seus jogadores; portanto, já sei que eu preciso do seguinte no `initialize`:

```
declare -A times
```

O comando `declare` permite criar variáveis no `bash`. Os argumentos que ele recebe mudam essa variável. Por exemplo, se eu quisesse criar um inteiro propriamente dito (sim, as vezes precisamos usar inteiros em shell script), poderíamos fazer `declare -i meu_inteiro`.

> Além de criar variáveis, também é possível ver o conteúdo de uma variável usando o `declare -p VAR`. Muito útil quando você está testando o script na linha de comando. Por exemplo, como `declare -p times` descreve a variável `times` depois que mandou criá-la?

Bem, agora temos um vetor associativo. Para acessar o valor dentro do vetor associativo. Para pegar o valor dentro da chave `Palmeiras`, usamos a seguinte expansão de variável:

```
time=${times[Palmeiras]}
```

> Note que o índice do vetor é sensível ao caso.

Assim, conseguimos acessar a string `time` que está associada ao índice `Palmeiras`. Posso dizer que queremos que os jogadores estejam separados entre vírgulas. Então, ao modificar a variável time, preciso colocar uma vírgula entre os jogadores anteriores e o novo. Podemos fazer isso com expansão de variável também:

```
time=${time:+${time},}${jogador}
```

A expansão `${var:+STRING}` vai se tornar `STRING` se e somente se `var` for uma variável preenchida. `STRING` é qualquer `STRING` válida, podendo inclusive ser uma expansão de variável, então eu pedi para colocar o valor de `time` seguido de uma vírgula. Se `var` não tiver valor ou estiver vazia, então a expansão `${var:+STRING}` vai retornar uma string vazia.

Não podemos nos esquecer de mandar a informação de volta para o vetor associativo, então, depois de atualizarmos o `time`, precisamos atualizar `times`:

```
times[Palmeiras]="${time}"
```

Ok, já sabemos ler uma linha (passo 1) e, sabendo quem é o jogador e o time, acrescer o jogador no time (passo 3). Também inicializamos nossos valores adequadamente na região `initialize`. Falta então apenas o passo 2.

Para saber quem é o `<TIME>` de uma linha, podemos usar expansão de variável sobre `LINHA`. Sabemos que o `<TIME>` é tudo que há antes do primeiro ponto-e-vírgula. Portanto, podemos pedir para a expansão remover tudo que há depois do ponto-e-vírgula e ficar apenas com o começo da variável:

```
nome_time=${LINHA%%;*}
```

A expansão `${var%%ENDPATTERN}` é uma expansão guloso que vai arrancar de `var` a terminação que casar com `ENDPATTERN`. Como a expansão é gulosa, o `ENDPATTERN` identificado acima `;*` permite que eu passe para `LINHA` o valor `PALMEIRAS;Fulano ponto-e-virgula;Sicranoso` que a expansão retornará apenas `PALMERIAS`.

Para identificar jogador, eu uso uma expansão de variável não gulosa. Pretendo excluir o começo da linha até chegar no primeiro ponto-e-vírgulo:

```
jogador=${LINHA#*;}
```

A expansão `${var#BEGINPATTERN}` é uma expansão não guloso que vai arrancar de `var` o prefixo que casar com `BEGINPATTERN`. Como a expansão é não gulosa, o `BEGINPATTERN` identificado acima como `*;` permite que eu passe para `LINHA` o valor `PALMEIRAS;Fulano ponto-e-virgula;Sicranoso` que a expansão retornará apenas `Fulano ponto-e-virgula;Sicranoso`.

Pronto, com essas duas expansões temos o passo 2 completo. Assim, juntando todos os pedaços, temos:

```
# bloco initialiaze
declare -A times

# passo 1: leitura da linha
while read LINHA; do
    # passo 2: identificação dos componentes da linha
    nome_time=${LINHA%%;*}
    jogador=${LINHA#*;}

    # passo 3: alterar o conteúdo do time 
    time=${times[${nome_time}]}
    time=${time:+${time},}${jogador}
    times[${nome_time}]="${time}"
done
```

Ok, já lemos nossos times da entrada padrão, agora só falta escrever =)

Como estamos em shell script, vamos assumir a saída padrão. Caso seja necessário direcionar essa saída padrão para um arquivo, use o redirecionamento de saída `./cria_times.sh > output.txt`. Você pode usar o redirecionamento de saída junto com o de entrada, não há problema.

Para loopar sobre as chaves do vetor associativo `times`, use a seguinte expansão de variável:

```
for time in "${!times[@]}"; do
    do_something
done
```

Como o formato de impressão é `<TIMES>` `;` `<JOGADORES>`, o `do_something` aqui será apenas a impressão:

```
for time in "${!times[@]}"; do
    echo "${time};${times[${time}]}"
done
```

Juntando a leitura com a impressão em um grande script, temos:

```
#!/bin/bash

# bloco initialiaze
declare -A times

# passo 1: leitura da linha
while read LINHA; do
    # passo 2: identificação dos componentes da linha
    nome_time=${LINHA%%;*}
    jogador=${LINHA#*;}

    # passo 3: alterar o conteúdo do time 
    time=${times[${nome_time}]}
    time=${time:+${time},}${jogador}
    times[${nome_time}]="${time}"
done

for time in "${!times[@]}"; do
    echo "${time};${times[${time}]}"
done
```

### UPDATE

Bem, esqueci de colocar uma fonte de pesquisa =]

A fonte que eu mais aprendi sobre `bash` e shell scripting de maneira geral foi o [Canivete Suíço](http://aurelio.net/shell/canivete/) do Aurélio Verde.

Outro ponto que vira e mexe eu olho é a [documentação oficial GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html), mas só passei a ler na fonte depois que eu me acostumei com as coisas estranhas no shell, depois de ler bastante o Canivete Suíço.

Comment: Jefferson, boa noite! Sua resposta é praticamente uma aula, muito obrigado! Também segui seus passos e cheguei no resultado esperado. Muito obrigado pelo tempo dedicado nessa resposta assim como as referências passadas! Irei estudar mais e mais sobre bash, já me salvou de alguns problemas  e trabalhos diários que seriam manuais. Abraço!

Comment: @hmm `bash ` é muito expressiva, sem falar que pode se tornar uma sopa de caracteres. Só por o código eu acho que não é gratificante o suficiente

Comment: Rapaz, dei uma olhada com mais calma no Canivete Suiço, animal! Vou até comprar o livro "Shell Script Profissional - Aurélio Marinho Jargas". Mais uma vez, obrigado! Grande abraço!

Comment: @hmm ótimo livro, recomendo =]

Comment: A saída em arquivo texto está estranha, podes dar uma olhada e me ajudar? http://bit.ly/2q4U7mQ queria que fosse um time com respectivos jogadores por linha

Comment: Após padronizar a quebra de linha (para somente \n) no arquivo de input o problema foi resolvido. Obrigado!

Comment: Como foi seu tratamento do fim da linha? Acho justo colocar na resposta, para ficar mais completa

Comment: Eu passei a tratar a leitura de cada linha, convertendo-a para o padrão do Linux caso esteja com padrão windows, com o comando "LINHA=`sed 's/\r$//'`"